# upload data from ms access to sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have already created a schema in sql server. is there any quick way to upload the data from table to table from msaccess to sql server.  what if the col names have changed slightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the "Import Data" function, you can map source columns to destination columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTS or SSIS depending on your version of sql server to load and transform data from any ODBC or OLEDB based data source.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using DTS, you could create a Linked Table inside Access (which points to SQL Server table) and create INSERT queries to do that.

If the table structure is identical & if it is a one time job, you could do copy-paste from Access Table to SQL Server Table (when that is linked).